# The time of my mac is messed up

Tags: time

This is a strange phenomenon. My time and date on the upper right corner is correctly set, but for some reason the time of every file is set incorrectly. For example, I just downloaded a youtube video (ABC song)from the internet, but I cannot find it from in the file recent, only

[image] [image]

The same is with my email. The one I just received is shown as created on 2017.

[image]

What's going on here?

I am on Macbook Pro mid 2014, Catalina

[image]

Comment: Does it only happen for this one file or for all? How did you download the video? Does the date match the creation date of the video on Youtube?

Comment: Downloaded files should show the date the file was actually created, not the date you downloaded it. Make a new TextEdit document & check the date. Your email shows the **To** address as a date, the received time shows as 8.58AM *today*.

Comment: Never noticed that. Thank for your reply. Would you please explain to me what the to date means?